# Mouse keeps freezing after using touchscreen in Windows 10 version 1709

Tags: windows-10, mouse, freeze, touchpad, windows-10-v1709

I have a Dell Inspiron 3541 with all original hardware (besides hard disk). Recently, after upgrading to Windows 10 v1709 (after 6 months of "Could not install" messages), the mouse (touchpad) freezes after using the touchscreen. It won't move until I press the `Ctrl` button. When I press the key, it freezes for a few seconds, and then the mouse works again.

It never did this on Windows 10 v1511, Windows 10 v1703, or Windows 8.

I have a Synaptics touchpad.

How do I fix this issue (stop the mouse from freezing)?

Comment: Do you have a compatible driver installed for both devices?

Comment: @Ramhound I have proper drivers for "Dell Touchpad" and "USB Input Device", but "HID-compliant touchscreen" has no required or loaded drivers.

Comment: What brand of Touchpad, typically I point people to the manufacture of the Touchpad, for drivers Dell is notorious for never updating the drivers for their Touchpad.  The manufacturer isn’t Dell